# Functx module and long strings with end of chars

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.1

I faced a problem with functx module dealing with strings with end of line characters. The following code should work (?)

```
declare %unit:test function test:substring-before-last() {

  let $title := 'Something
blah other'

  let $expected-title := 'Something
blah'

  return unit:assert-equals(functx:substring-before-last($title, ' other'),
    $expected-title)
};
```

However it gives a failure

> "Something&#xA;blah" expected, "Something&#xA;blah other"
> returned.

Removing line breaking makes the test working. What I don't understand? :)

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the definition or implementation of the functx function http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_substring-before-last.html:

```
declare function functx:substring-before-last
  ( $arg as xs:string? ,
    $delim as xs:string )  as xs:string {

   if (matches($arg, functx:escape-for-regex($delim)))
   then replace($arg,
            concat('^(.*)', functx:escape-for-regex($delim),'.*'),
            '$1')
   else ''
 } ;
```

and the regular expression dot `.` matching and the `replace` default "If the input string contains no substring that matches the regular expression, the result of the function is a single string identical to the input string."; if you add the flags `m` argument

```
declare function functx:substring-before-last
  ( $arg as xs:string? ,
    $delim as xs:string )  as xs:string {

   if (matches($arg, functx:escape-for-regex($delim)))
   then replace($arg,
            concat('^(.*)', functx:escape-for-regex($delim),'.*'),
            '$1', 'm')
   else ''
 } ;
```

you get the right match and replacement and comparison.

Comment: Thanks! It's always a good idea to take a look at the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not work either reliable. Take this example, where the word 'end is being removed from both lines, not just the last line:

[image: example]